# Passing a URL into a JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl, callfire

I'm attempting to execute a curl statement in PHP that uses a JSON array. I'll post my code below with a little explanation of what im trying to do

```
function doPost($url, $user, $password, $params) {
  $authentication = 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("$user:$password");
  $http = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
  curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json', $authentication));
  return curl_exec($http);
}

$link = "http://link.it/i.htm?id=55&key=23987gf2389fg";
$phone = '5551231234';
$phone = '1' . $phone;

//Write message
$msg = "Click here " . $link;
$params = '[{"phoneNumber":"'.$phone.'","message":"'.$msg.'"}]';

//Send message
$return = doPost('https://api.link.com','username','password',$params);
echo $return;
```

Params ends up being

```
$params = '[{"phoneNumber":"15551231234","message":"Click here http://link.it/i.htm?id=55&key=23987gf2389fg"}]';
```

All looks good. And the JSON array that is being created by params actually works perfectly if there is no link inside the $msg variable. I am able to execute a successful CURL call. The only time it fails is when I add a link to my $msg variable.

I have contact the support team for the API and they inform me that everything should work on their end.

At this point I am guessing that the link needs to be escaped somehow before it can be written into the JSON array. I have tried escaping the colons and forward slashes with back slashes, but it does not fix the problem. Is there anyone that can shed some light on how to pass a url?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: **Don't** craft JSON by hand. Use the PHP [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. It takes care of creating correct JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't construct your JSON manually.  Construct and array or object then call json_encode() on it.

```
$params = array();
$object = array("phone"=>$phone, "message"=>$linkMsg);
$params[] = (object) $object;

$param_json_string = json_encode($params);
```

Then when submitting the JSON via POST with curl, you need to specify the lenght of the string in the header.

```
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            array( 'Content-Type: application/json', 
                   'Content-Length: '. strlen($param_json_string)));
```

Of course, this is in addition to other headers like authentication you're setting (as I see you do in your `doPost()` method).

Comment: Wait until the stackoverflow elves approve the edit to this post so that you can see the code example

Comment: Unfortunately tried it and there is still an error being returned by the curl call. It must be an error with the API. The json being encoded is perfect `"[{"phoneNumber":"15551231234","message":"Click here http:\/\/link.it\/i.html?id=55&key=247a626c8b28293bf1e5"}]"`

Comment: A valid JSON string still might not be valid to use in a HTTP request, by urlencoding it it will escape any special HTTP characters like whitespace, `&`, `?`, and such .

Comment: All the help is awesome. I tried 2 things. I urlencoded the entire JSON string `$params = json_encode($params); $safeParams = urlencode($params);` which returned the error `{"httpStatusCode":422,"internalCode":0,"message":"Unable to convert entity : Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@a14933; line: 1, column: 2], error type: JsonParseException"}` when I executed the curl call.

Comment: I also tried urlencode on just the link in the message `$linkMsg = "Click here " . $link; $linkMsg = urlencode($linkMsg);` with a much more ambiguous response that just said there was an error in the message. Hmmmm...

Comment: Ooops. Brain farted... For posting json in curl you don't need to url encode, but you must specify the string length.  updating my answer

Comment: @AlexKonetchy check out the edit to my answer for POSTing with curl

Comment: @AlexKonetchy The lenght of the content with the content type should be enough for the recieving API to handle it properly.

Comment: Super helpful! I added the specification for the length of the string in the header. I am still receiving an error in the response. It must be an issue with the API itself! Thank you so much for all the help you've given

Comment: @AlexKonetchy did you remove the urlencoding?

Comment: @Ray yes I did. Is it needed?

Comment: @AlexKonetchy it shouldn't be if you're specifying the length.  The issue seems to be on the API side not liking the link.  Will it work with something simple and without special characters like: "hello_world_test"

Comment: Yes that's my thought as well. I tried "Hello, World!" and it works as expected. So it's obvious that the link itself is breaking it, although the support for the API tell me that links shouldn't cause problems. Will dig deeper into the API and see if there is a solution in the documentation.